# Azure In-Role Cache SessionState no response

Tags: c#, azure, session-state, azure-web-roles

I am using In-Role caching for my sessionstate.
I've done everything that [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/gg185668.aspx) says, but somehow my page keeps loading when I request it in my browser. When I remove the  element from my web.config and do a IIS reset my site starts up normally and works.

I am using Azure SDK 2.3 and installed the NuGet package. My sessionState element looks like this:

```
  <sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AFCacheSessionStateProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AFCacheSessionStateProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider, Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache" cacheName="default" dataCacheClientName="default" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

My dataCacheClients element looks like this:

```
<dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient name="default" isCompressionEnabled="true">
        <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="role.name" />
    </dataCacheClient>
</dataCacheClients>
```

When I browse to my blob storage in Azure I can see that 7c2f7246b22b4d701692f695eda811ed__Role.Name__ConfigBlob is being updated so the connection should be there.

Does anybody have an idea what's wrong?

Comment: Which version of caching library are you using? Nuget typically installs the latest version but SDK's usually have dependency on specific version.

Comment: I am using 2.4.0.0. Should I install 2.3.0.0?

Comment: Yes please. This is what the Nuget page (http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching/) says: `This NuGet package can only be used with the Windows Azure SDK version 2.4 of Windows Azure Cache.`. You can install 2.3.1 from here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Caching/2.3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Azure SDK 2.4 and that fixed the problem. Thanks @Gaurav Mantri!